Regular expression for the language: All words over {a,b,c} such that #a(w)>=2 and #b(w)>=2
Seeking help with a regex task: Constructing a pattern for words over {a, b,c} with #a(w)≥2 and #b(w)≥2
c has no limitations
. Need solution assistance.
example for words that are in the language:
aaabbb
abbaba
bbaaab
ababab
baabba
abbaab
bbaaba
Thanks!

Regex might not be the best choice for this. I'm not saying it can't be done, but I think the solution will be a lot more complicated that using whatever functions you have available in the programming language you are using.

Unfortunatley, i'm not allowed to use programming as it, this is from a quiz in ToC/Automata Theory.

So you just need a pattern that matches strings that contain 2 or more instances of a and b each?

Correct, I tried it first with DFA, but minimization of the DFA will take hours.

Like this? https://regex101.com/r/YLkgyD/1

@ShaharDavid What do you mean by "minimization of the DFA will take hours"? Can you show the DFA you have?

@CAustin this seems more a computer science/formal language related problems, so things like lookahead probably won't be possible.

@derpirscher You're correct, i've tried to convert what CAustin provided, but i failed unfortunately, Note: i made a little change to the question, it's over {a,b,c} where c has no limitations.

The straight forward approach is the following: Generally there are 6 different patterns your regex must match:  aabb, abab,abba,baab, baba and bbaa. Whatever comes before, after or inbetween the letters of each of the patterns is irrelevant. So the straight forward regex for this would be
((a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*) |
((a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*) |
((a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*) |
((a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*) |
((a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*) |
((a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*) 

Of course this is a monstrosity you would never use in a real world application. But for a CS test (if there are no other requirements) it will do the job ...

Thank you! It works but unfortunately i need it to be as short as possible haha.
It's for a test

Is it a requirement for the test to be as short as possible? Or just because you don't want to write too much. For a test it's a valid approach to use the straight forward solution which you can come up with quickly, instead of the "pretty" solution which takes much time to find ... In a test I'd rather spend 5 minutes writing down a solution I came up with in 30 seconds, than spend 10 minutes searching for a solution I can write down in 30 seconds ...

You can slightly simplify @derpirscher approach by noting that the solutions (in their simplest form) are of the form: aabb, bbaa or one of ab or ba followed by a second ab or ba:
^c*
(?:
    (?:a[ac]*b|b[bc]*a)c*(?:a[ac]*b|b[bc]*a) |
    (?:a[bc]*a[ac]*b[ac]*b) |
    (?:b[ac]*b[bc]*a[bc]*a)
)
[bca]*$

Regex demo on regex101
Note regex has added whitespace for readability, either remove these or use the x (extended - ignore whitespace) flag as I have done in the demo.

There are a number of ways to do this.
One approach is to consider the different possible ways that the word can start, and then see what must remain. You can, for example, break the possibilities into six cases:

aa followed by a word with at least two b's
aba followed by a word with at least one b
aab followed by a word with at least one a
baa followed by a word with at least one b
bab followed by a word with at least one a
bb followed by a word with at least two a's

I trust that you can take it from there?

Thank you so much, but i've made a little change - it's over {a,b,c} where c has no limitations

@ShaharDavid: No problem, you just need to add a bunch of c*'s everywhere. :-)
